# Exit from firmware download mode

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung, device-firmware

Can I get out from firmware download mode without downloading new one? I see horrible message:

```
Downloading...
Do not turn off target!!!
```

What will happens if I power off my Samsung S4?

Comment: If you are not in the process of flashing another firmware, it's safe to just power off your device.

Answer (score 0):

the power should not be turned off during the Flashing.... if there is a progress bar ongoing you must not turn the power off otherwise simply hold the power button or remove the battery to restart... no problem

Answer (score 0):

You can get out of this download mode by pressing and holding **Power** button for *10-20 seconds* while its inside download mode. Alternatively, you can also simply pull out and reinsert battery and start your phone normally. Unless you are flashing a firmware or similar, this wont cause any harm to your phone.